# Rails asset pipline and Jquery plugins issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, asset-pipeline

I am using rails with jquery gem.

I have the following in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Do these declarations include files in order ?

I am using a jquery pluging textareaexpander (http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-1/)

I am getting a js error

```
jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
```

on almost the last line of the plugin which is something like below

```
// initialize all expanding textareas
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
})
```

I don't get it ? is it because jQuery hasn't been loaded. why is TextAreaExpander still not defined ?

For reference below is the rest of the code in the plugin file.

```
(function($) {
// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
// resize a textarea
function ResizeTextarea(e) {
// event or initialize element?
e = e.target || e;
// find content length and box width
var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
if (vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) {
if (hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth)) e.style.height = "0px";
var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax));
e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
e.style.height = h + "px";
e.valLength = vlen;
e.boxWidth = ewidth;
}
return true;
};
// initialize
this.each(function() {
// is a textarea?
if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "textarea") return;
// set height restrictions
var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);
// initial resize
ResizeTextarea(this);
// zero vertical padding and add events
if (!this.Initialized) {
this.Initialized = true;
$(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);
$(this).bind("keyup", ResizeTextarea).bind("focus", ResizeTextarea);
}
});
return this;
};
})(jQuery); 

// initialize all expanding textareas
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
});
```

As you can see the function TextAreaExpander was first defined by extending jQuery and then called on document ready but still not working. I have similar issues with other plugins on of them is chosen.js.

If any one can point out the issue and elaborate what is causing this, because for me this doesn't make any sense ( but obviously i am missing a point here).

Relevant code

```
development.rb

config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true

application.rb
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0
```

Ok so I did the experiment suggested to check if it is a syntax issue, turns out it isn't.

I did another experiment, If I remove the line

```
//= require_tree .
```

from application.js and instead replace it with

```
//= require_self
```

and in my view file (the view that is being rendered) I add the following at the end

```
= javascript_include_tag 'libs/jquery.textarea-exapander'
```

all seems to work perfectly. Any ideas now ?

more info

```
app/assets/javascript
  |- application.js
  |- chosen.jquery.js
  |- admin/
     |- categories.js.coffee
  |- libs/
     |- jquery.textarea-exapander.js
     |- modernizr.js
     |- platformselector.js
     |- waypoints.js
  |- gmaps4ails/
     |- gmaps4rails.base.js
     |- gmaps4rails.bing.js
     |- gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js
```

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

code from my layout

```
%html
  %head
    %title Whatever
    %link{type:"text/css",rel:"stylesheet", href:"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails'
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'shared/header'
    %div#main.inside.topadd
      = yield
      %div.wrapper
    =render 'shared/footer'
    = yield :scripts
```

The above setup does not work

The following setup works

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

inside my registrations/new.html.haml

```
some bla bla bla bla haml code

= javascript_include_tag 'libs/jquery.textarea-exapander'
```

this works, the same is true for the other plugin chosen.js if I include in after the view it works otherwise it gives the same error that .chosen is not a function.

So as from the comments it looks like something is wrong with my local setup

I have noticed another strange thing in the html on heroku and local

this is the body class on heroku

```
linux js gecko gecko_20100101 firefox firefox_12_0 firefox_12 gecko_12_0
```

but on my local the body class is

```
js no-flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths linux gecko gecko_20100101 firefox firefox_12_0 firefox_12 gecko_12_0 js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths
```

I am also seeing this my every rails app locally

```
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; display: none;"></div>
```

after body starts and

```
<div id="supersized-loader"></div>
<div id="supersized"></div>
```

before body ends
I am not using neither including color box by far...

What is going on ??

Thanks

Comment: where have you placed the plugin's file?  Is it is in app/assets/javascripts?  Also post your application.rb so we can look at how your assets pipeline is set up,  also post environments/development.rb if that is appropriate,  anything with config.asset* in it.

Comment: I have updated the post with relevant code. yes my plugin files are inside app/assets/javascripts and they are being loaded on the page

Comment: exactly what is the browser saying about the js error?  not a function?  What version of jQuery was used when that plugin was developed,  the Blog post was 2009,  and I don't recognize the selector syntax,  can you change it to JQuery('.expand').TextAreaExpander(); ,  just to see if it's a selector syntax issue.  Assuming the only elements elements on your page with class="expand" are text_areas.

Comment: the error says jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander is not a function. I am using jQuery version 1.7.2. I dont think it is an issue with version compatabiltiy.

Comment: I am updating my post will more info kindly take a look at it

Comment: Bizzare,  so you put your javascript stuff in app/assets/javascripts/libs.  The require_self isn't needed unless you've placed some other JavaScript in the manifest along with the directives.  Have you been posting the COMPLETE manifest?  Post the complete layout of app/assets/javascripts directory and the contents of any manifests AND the javascript_include_tag invocation you are using.

Comment: I have updated the post with more info that you asked for

Comment: i am also quickly doing a sample app and pushing to github to show you the issue

Comment: I wonder if it might be a typo issue? The references to the file name all say "exapander" and but the function you're calling says "expander"

Comment: here is the link to sample app, you can see problems with both chosen and textareaexpander plugin

https://github.com/mabid/chosen-problem

Comment: @Emily then why doesn't the same issue arise when I include it after my view ?

Comment: @RadBrad the branch named working has the code that works, and the master shows the issue with both chosen and textareaexapander

Comment: The master version of your app works fine for me

Comment: @FrederickCheung thats really weird. What can be possibly wrong then ??

Comment: @FrederickCheung you don't get any errors on the firebug or your js console and the chosen works for you ? I am on rails (3.2.3), jquery-rails (2.0.2) which has jquery v1.7.2

Comment: No errors and it seems to work just fine. Text expander stuff ok too.

Comment: very strange...I am going to put this on heroku now..

Comment: @FrederickCheung can you kindly provide the generated html of the page that you see ?

Comment: works on heroku also... whats wrong with my local setup :S :S

Comment: I have noticed another strange thing in the html on heroku and local

this is the body class on heroku 

linux js gecko gecko_20100101 firefox firefox_12_0 firefox_12 gecko_12_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after hours. The issue was not where all of us were looking for it.

I had nginx running on my local machine, the conf of which was pointing to another project of mine and the public directory was set to that project, so the path /assets/application.js was being served by nginx directly from the public/assets/ directory of the other project. and since the other project was on heroku I used to precompile assets locallay so a compiled application was js was created inside app/assets which was being served.

Thanks a lot for your help guys, Your comments and discussion helped me figure out that the issue was with local machine only and that something bad was going on with my configuration.

Thanks again